# How do I create the panel shadow effect as found on Google Maps, using GWT?

Tags: gwt, maps, panel, shadow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML/CSS: How does Google create this drop shadow over their maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497364/html-css-how-does-google-create-this-drop-shadow-over-their-maps)

Using GWT and the Google Maps component, how do I best create the "panel shadow" effect as seen in the screenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the `box-shadow` CSS property (make sure the browsers you are targeting supports it)

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 5px 5px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 5px 5px #000000;
box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 5px 5px #000000;
```

Use `rgba` color spec with opacity to get a "lighter" shadow.

Comment: That does work beautifully on non-map based panels, but not on the Google Maps composites. Do I need to create something positioned above the maps component?

Comment: Grab a firebug and inspect some elements here: http://kartor.eniro.se/ - I'm not entirely sure on google maps, but the principle is the same.